# LINQ Guid toString()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Hi this seems like it should work,

```
from something in collectionofsomestuff       
select new SelectListItem(){Text = something.Name, Value = something.SomeGuid.ToString(), Selected = false};
```

When I try to do this it doesn't work give me error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: From which scope do "Name" and "SomeGuid" come? It's not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all CLR methods can be used with Linq-to-Entities.  ToString() seems to be one of them.

Take a look at [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx).

Maybe try setting the GUID to a string variable explicitly, outside of Linq.

```
string myGuid = SomeGuid.ToString();

from something in collectionofsomestuff       
select new SelectListItem(){Text = Name, Value = myGuid, Selected = false};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the records in the db,and then turn them to a list or a array use ToList() or ToArray().Then use the object.
For example(it is LINQ to Entities ):

```
var list = collectionofsomestuff.select(c => c).ToList();
from something in list
select new SelectListItem(){Text = something.Name, Value = something.SomeGuid.ToString(), Selected = false};
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  You can also use `.AsQueryable` before calling `.Select(new SelectListItem(...`

Answer (score 4):

I don't speak Linq query expressions too well, but the following should do the trick:

```
collectionofsomestuff //here it's LinqToEntities
    .Select(something=>new{something.Name,something.SomeGuid})
    .ToArray() //From here on it's LinqToObjects
    .Select(s=>new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = s.Name, 
            Value = s.SomeGuid.ToString(), 
            Selected = false
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a foreach like so

```
           List<SelectListItem> list  = new List<SelectListItem>();
       foreach (SomeThing something in collectionofsomestuff)
       {
           list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text = something.Name,Selected = false,Value = something.SomeGuid.ToString()});
       }
```

this is the only way I could get it to work..it wasn't what i was hoping to do tough..

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor for SelectListItem that accepts your Value as a Guid and ToString it there.   Now call your query like so:

```
from something in collectionofsomestuff select new SelectListItem(something.Name, something.SomeGuid, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I ended up changing my object's definition to get around the problem. It's a complete hack, but it allows me to populate the data straight from the query:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeviceInfo
{
    public Guid DeviceGuid
    {
        set
        {
            DeviceID = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceID { get; set; }
}
```

And the query works as designed because it has something else doing the conversion for it:

```
devices.AddRange(from d in ae.UserDevices
                    select new DeviceInfo
                    {
                        DeviceGuid = d.DeviceID
                    }
```

It makes the object a little messier, but makes dealing with the Guid in the query so much easier.