# Switching from LinqToXYZ to LinqToObjects

Tags: c#, linq

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512543/linq-guid-tostring), it got me thinking...

I often use this pattern:

```
collectionofsomestuff //here it's LinqToEntities
    .Select(something=>new{something.Name,something.SomeGuid})
    .ToArray() //From here on it's LinqToObjects
    .Select(s=>new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = s.Name, 
            Value = s.SomeGuid.ToString(), 
            Selected = false
        })
```

Perhaps I'd split it over a couple of lines, but essentially, at the `ToArray` point, I'm effectively enumerating my query and storing the resulting sequence so that I can further process it with all the goodness of a full CLR to hand.

As I have no interest in any kind of manipulation of the intermediate list, I use `ToArray` over `ToList` as there's less overhead.

I do this all the time, but I wonder if there is a better pattern for this kind of problem?

Comment: Just wanted to throw a quick comment out that ToArray() and ToList() in this context are equivalent. Open up reflector and look at Enumerable.ToArray() and you'll find it implements an inline array list that expands by a factor of 2 as it fills up. This is the same behavior as List<T>, so the two options are more or less equivalent. Always remember, IEnumerable has no count information exposed to it, so an arraylist style algorithm is required for the ToArray() method

Comment: This peaked my interest, so I popped open reflector to see what's going on. ToArray makes use of the System.Linq.Buffer<TElement>. Upon construction of the Buffer, it appears that an attempt is made to cast the Enumerable to an ICollection and if the cast succeeds, to make use of the Count property to optimize array allocation. The constuctor overload, List<T>(IEnumerable source), also uses this trick.

Comment: Yuppers, It does, however, in the case of a LinqToEntities query, the query result is (almost undoubtedly) an anonymous IEnumerable type, which WON'T implement ICollection. I remember looking at things like Enumerable.Count(), which do the exact same test. Kind of an interesting decision on Microsoft's part to do the tests, it rubbed me the wrong way at the time, but now I'm starting to think it was a good idea...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to satisfy my ponderings. I'm off to bed to dream about this now :)

Comment: The ToArray function will use the ToList algorithm, but then copy the data to an array of exactly the right size. If you are going to have these results hanging around for a while, ToArray will be more space-efficient.

Comment: @gabe : I saw a different story. ToList is a wrapper around the constructor List<T>(IEnumerable source). If the size of the enumerable can be deduced (by casting to ICollection) then the allocated array is exactly that size. So there really isn't that much space overhead (unless you add to the list... that might hurt)

Comment: I've seen, and written, code that uses ToArray and ToList to buffer results but I don't really like its usage since it doesn't describe your intent. You don't care about having an array or list; you want to ensure further operations are not handled by the original linq provider and instead performed on a reusable in-memory collection. Wouldn't it be better to write a ToBuffer extension method for IQueryable that uses whatever collection type(s) are appropriate? Maybe also provide an optional limit argument that limits the number of results that can be buffered?

Comment: spender: You saw the same story I did. When you pass it an ICollection the two techniques are identical. But for the usual LinqToEntities query ToArray will give you a smaller array at the expense of an extra copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much better option: [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)

Usage is similar:

```
collectionofsomestuff //here it's LinqToEntities
    .Select(something=>new{something.Name,something.SomeGuid})
    .AsEnumerable() //From here on it's LinqToObjects
    .Select(s=>new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = s.Name, 
            Value = s.SomeGuid.ToString(), 
            Selected = false
        })
```

This, however, doesn't force a full copy to be made like `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, and preserves any deferred execution from your provider.

Comment: Only better if you aren't doing significant work in the remainder of the Linq query. If you are doing significant work, the SqlConnection will remain open for the entirety of the operation. Calling ToArray() or ToList() completes the entire query and closes the SqlConnection at that point.

Comment: ...I've seen it a million times and it barely registered. Nice one.

Comment: So would the be some sort of buffering of the source stream in this case? Or would we literally be pulling results one at a time? (I'm pretty ignorant at this level)

Comment: I'm going to write up another answer for this, not enough room here to explain...

Answer (score 5):

Reed's answer is indeed correct, if you are doing simple assignments in the remainder of the LINQ query. However, if you are doing significant work or computation in the LinqToObjects section of your query, his solution has some slight problem if you consider the connections to the underlying data source:

Consider:

```
collectionofsomestuff //here it's LinqToEntities
    .Select(something=>new{something.Name,something.SomeGuid})
    .AsEnumerable() //From here on it's LinqToObjects
    .Select(s=>new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = s.Name, 
            Value = s.SomeGuid.ToString(), 
            OtherValue = someCrazyComputationOnS(s)
        })
```

If you can imagine for a second the code for the LinqToEntities select function (highly simplified, but you should get the picture), it might look something like:

```
using(SqlConnection con = createConnection())
{
    using(SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
   {
       con.Open();
       com.CommandText = createQuery(expression);

       using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while(reader.Read())
           {
               yield return createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This method supports the traditional Linq deferred execution patterns. This means that whenever a result is read from the reader, it will be "yielded" back to the caller, and the next value won't be read until the caller requests it.

So, in the above code, the sequence of execution for a result set of 5 records would be:

```
con.Open();

reader.Read();
createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
// at this point there is a yield back to the caller
someCrazyComputationOnS(s);


reader.Read();
createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
// at this point there is a yield back to the caller
someCrazyComputationOnS(s);


reader.Read();
createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
// at this point there is a yield back to the caller
someCrazyComputationOnS(s);


reader.Read();
createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
// at this point there is a yield back to the caller
someCrazyComputationOnS(s);


reader.Read();
createClrObjectFromReader(reader);
// at this point there is a yield back to the caller
someCrazyComputationOnS(s);

// ONLY here does the connection finally get closed:
con.Close();
```

Although this does preserve the deferred execution pattern. This is not optimal in this situation. Calling ToList() or ToArray() would cause the entire raw query results to be buffered into an Array or List, after which point the SqlConnection could be closed. Only after the SqlConnection had been closed would the calls to someCrazyComputationOnS(s) actually occur.

In most cases, this isn't a concern and Reed's answer is indeed correct, but in the rare case you are doing large amounts of work on your dataset, you definitely want to buffer the results before proceeding with large LinqToObjects queries.

Comment: Thanks, deferred execution is still not fully understood in some places... I like to make the worst case point about deferred execution, just to make sure people keep it in mind when they are implementing solutions...

Comment: The flip side of this argument is that the deferred processing lets you chum through gigantic amounts of data without incurring the cost of loading it all. That can be *very* handy.

Comment: +1: The flip side of this, though, is if you do something like Take(10), you're really hurting yourself...

Comment: Agreed, you have to realize which side of the .ToList() or .ToArray() that various things go on. Take(10) or similar should go before the ToList() or ToArray() call, and throwing them on the other side does create serious problems... Just another thing to think about