# Linq Projection Question

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, projection

I'm trying to do the following:

```
from c in db.GetAllContactsQuery()
select new
{
   ID= c.ID,
   LastName = c.LastName,
   FirstName = c.FirstName,
   Email = c.Email,
   City =c.City+" "+c.State
}
```

The issue i'm running into is that if c.City or c.State are null, the City property returns null. How can I put a function right beside that `City=` declaration?

I'd really like to know if its possible to do something like this (this does not work):

```
from c in db.GetAllContactsQuery()
select new
{
   ID= c.ID,
   LastName = c.LastName,
   FirstName = c.FirstName,
   Email = c.Email,
   City ={ c=>
         //completely sweet function in here
         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.City))
                return "booyah";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a null coalescing operator? If the value on the left of ?? is null, it is substituted for the value on the right.

```
from c in db.GetAllContactsQuery()
select new
{
   ID= c.ID,
   LastName = c.LastName,
   FirstName = c.FirstName,
   Email = c.Email,
   City =(c.City??"")+" "+(c.State??"")
}
```

In answer to your comment, you need to use AsEnumerable so you can use full CLR goodness:

```
db.GetAllContactsQuery()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c=>new
        {
           ID= c.ID,
           LastName = c.LastName,
           FirstName = c.FirstName,
           Email = c.Email,
           City =MyClrMethod(c.City,c.State)
        })
```

If `db.GetAllContactsQuery()` returns many additional fields, select the ones of interest before the `AsEnumerable` clause to narrow bandwidth requirements.

Comment: I believe you are right, but is there any way to open up a function here, in case i want to do some more logic? Such as special formatting based upon the country they live in

Comment: Is this Linq to Objects or Linq2SomethingElse?

Comment: Its being run off of LinqToSql

Comment: Why is that AsEnumberable required?

Comment: Linq to Sql only supports a limited number of methods. AsEnumerable effectively turns your Linq2Sql into Linq2Objects which allows access to the full CLR.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512639/switching-from-linqtoxyz-to-linqtoobjects

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you for throwing that link in there I had no idea about the underpinnings of AsEnumerable. Thanks again!